# Errors for no reason

Tags: java, android, debugging, compiler-errors

I tried to run the code to test if the program works, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I am getting an error that the `fullscreen_contents_controls` can't be resolved (line 54) and a syntax error when I can't find one (line 100). Can you help debug it?

Here are the errors:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   fullscreen_content_controls cannot be resolved or is not a field    Opening.java    /MagicSquaresGame/src/com/mtprogramming/magicsquaresgame    line 54 Java Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody Opening.java    /MagicSquaresGame/src/com/mtprogramming/magicsquaresgame    line 100    Java Problem

Code:

```
/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 * 
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class Opening extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = false;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.


        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: There is no such thing as an error "for no reason".  There's a reason, you just don't know it yet.  The sooner you get out of the habit of saying "there's no reason", the better you'll be as a programmer.

Comment: Hint: the reason is what is being printed in the compiler error message. Read it and paste it: it contains valuable information. And post the relevant code. What you posted doesn't contain any fullscreen_contents_controls.

Comment: it would be great to have either (1) copied the code with line numbers included, or (2) let us know which lines are lines 54 & 100.  You cannot expect others to do more work to help you out than you do yourself when posting the problem.

In short, you get what you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that "fullscreen_content_controls" exists in your xml layout?

Your controlsView should have an id attribute

```
<controlsView
    android:id='full_content_controls'
    ...
    >
```

Comment: In regards to your line 100 error, you have missed the closing brace on the onCreate function:

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

It should go after the comments.

Comment: The error fixed by Dolchio should also take care of the line 56 error, since your line 100 error was preventing the build from taking place and the R file to be properly generated (therefore, not generating the R.id.fullscreen_content_controls in the first place).